# Browser Downloading PHP files instead of opening them

Tags: php, .htaccess

I edited my htaccess file to parse all html files as php.file like so:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

pages are being downloaded instead of being opened/redirected in the browser, i have never had this issue of my other hosting server so i am a bot confused right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `x-httpd-php5` and add `SetHander`:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .htm
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .html

<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: That didn't work but i did however notice that the server's PHP version is set to 5.2, could that be the reason?

Comment: @BlankEDjok Do you have access to the `httpd.conf` file (assuming apache...)? If so, check what it uses for php.